# Making string content strikethrough in Google Apps

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm faced with a trivial but not-quick-to-get thing: I need to set the font of a string as a strike-through style.

I've tried search for similar solution on Stackoverflow but it wasn't much instructive and helpful.

What I do have:

```
var bookingDetails = "\nЗаезд: " + row[0] + "\nВыезд: " + row[1] + "\nНомер: " + "«" + row[2] + "»" + "\nТип размещения: " + row[3] + "\n" + "\nЦена за ночь: " + row[4] + " руб." + "\nВнесённый депозит: " + row[8] + " руб." + "\n" + "\nИмя и фамилия гостя: " + row[5] + "\nМобильный телефон: " + row[6] + "\nЭлектронная почта: " + row[7] + "\n" + "\nПримечание: " + row[11];
```

I need to make the content of `bookingDetails` <s>striked out</s> without changing anything in the sheet itself. I tried `bookingDetails.setFontLine("line-through")` but it didn't help by showing the error of "TypeError: Cannot find function setFontLine in object...".

Please, help me fix it.

Just letting you know that I'm very thankful for your attempt to help me in advance.

UPD № 1: I'm using Google Spreadsheets. If it does make sense.
UPD № 2: If it is not possible to make this strike-through transformation just in the script not explicitly in cells then I should add that `bookingDetails` is used in the email body to be sent through `MailApp.sendEmail`. So if it possible to transform the contents of `bookigndbetails` directly in the message body then let me know how to make it as quick as possible on the example of my script.

Hoping that know my goal is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a function that will set strikethrough the text

```
function setStrikethrough(range) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Get the current spreadsheet.
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];                  // Select the first sheet.
    var cell = sheet.getRange(range);               // Use supplied arguments
    cell.setFontLine("line-through");                     // set strikethrough
}
```

You can call this method like this (this will set the line style of the given `range` to 'line-through'):

```
// specify the range
setStrikethrough("B2:C4");
```

See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/

Comment: The error is "Cannot find function setStrikethrough in object Заезд: Sun May 01 2016 02:00:00 GMT+0500 (YEKT)".

Comment: You get this error because you're calling methods on `String`, but you should be calling them on `Text` objects.

Comment: I'm using Google Spreadsheets and I have `var data = dataRange.getValues();`. Should I apply your findings to `data`?

Comment: Or `sheet` which is `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();`?

Comment: and afterwards should I add `bookingDetails.setStrikethrough(true)`?

Comment: No, forget about `bookingDetails.setStrikethrough(true)`. It works for google docs, but not for google spreadsheets (I thought you were working with google docs at first). The line `cell.setFontLine("line-through");` in `setStrikethrough(range)` method above will set the strike through.

Comment: But again I don't need to change anything in cells of Google Spreadsheets sheet. I just need to change the content of the variable in the script.

Comment: Can I use it as `setStrikethrough(bookingDetails);`?

Comment: @RLearnsR, you cannot set a style of a variable, you set the style of text that is visible to the user. In this case, if you have specific cells with text that you want to strikethrough, you call `setStrikethrough(range)`. The argument `range` that you pass in is the range of the cells for example `"B2"` (single cell) or `"B2:C4"` a range of cells.

Comment: Yes it is clear but can I just transform the contents of `bookingDetails` to text and then strikethrough this text? What I mean to point is that to make a text of  `var bookingDetails = "\nЗаезд: " + row[0] + "\nВыезд: " + row[1] + "\nНомер: " + "«" + row[2] + "»" + "\nТип размещения: " + row[3] + "\n" + "\nЦена за ночь: " + row[4] + " руб." + "\nВнесённый депозит: " + row[8] + " руб." + "\n" + "\nИмя и фамилия гостя: " + row[5] + "\nМобильный телефон: " + row[6] + "\nЭлектронная почта: " + row[7] + "\n" + "\nПримечание: " + row[11];` and get plain text of it with striking it through.

Comment: Google Spreadsheets does not provide `Text` class for that (Google docs does). Check the link the post for available classes in Google Spreadsheets. So, what you're saying is not possible to do with Google Spreadsheets.

Comment: Okey if so maybe I need add that I use `bookingDetails` for sending an email through `MailApp.sendEmail`. Thus can I transform it to HTML in the message body and then add `<del></del>`?

Comment: You should specify details of the question in the original post, to make sure the answers you get are relevant.

Comment: Yes, I respectively did it.